# Validate route {prop} on request

Tags: php, regex, laravel, routes, uri

Hi guys how can i validate route {prop} on request
Exemple:
      http request: 
     - www.domain.com/page/4/name_of_page

Code:
 
         `$Route->get('page/{id}/{pageName}');`

I whant to replicate some similiar to laravel route request.

How Laravel work under the hood, how he replace the props on uri request
 - I'm trying to use regex to update the route, so when i check if route exists the prop are already replaced. But not work when I have a second prop {pageName}

what is the best approach for solve this problem?

Thank's for your time

Comment: This question is IMHO too much opinion based, you shoud give us some sample code and clear error statement. "the best approach for solve this problem" is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly validated route `{prop}`.

**Using Request file**

```
class YourRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'pageName' => 'required|max:255',
            'id' => 'required|exist:posts',
        ];
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $data = parent::all();
        $data['id'] = $this->route('id');
        $data['pageName'] = $this->route('pageName');

        return $data;
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Using Validate in controller**

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, $pageName)
{

 $request->request->set('pageName', $pageName);
 $request->request->set('id', $id);

 $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'id' => 'required|exist:posts',
        'pageName' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: the problem is. I whant to be dynamic {props}. On example i use {id} and {pageName}.

But can be other things.

Maybe the only solution is make prop static like

1 - `$Route->get('page/{prop}/{prop}', 'PageController');` replace de {prop} with uri explode
2 - Update de array with routes authorized exemple( page/2/name )
3 - Then because the route exists i can proceed to the controller

But I'm not sure if this is the best option.

Comment: You can't user same name `$Route->get('page/{prop}/{prop}', 'PageController');` prop in route. If you want to set `pageName` as optional useg  `$Route->get('page/{prop}/{pageName?}', 'PageController');` code